# Error when writing metadata to mp3 in Clojure with zsau/id3

Tags: audio, clojure, mp3, id3

I'm new to Clojure and I'm trying to write some metadata to a mp3 file. I decided to use [zsau/id3](https://clojars.org/zsau/id3) for this task.

After I created a new project with `lein new app`, I added zsau/id3 as a dependency in my `project.clj`:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [zsau/id3 "0.1.2"]]
```

This is my `core.clj` file:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require [id3])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (id3/overwrite-tag "t.mp3"
     (id3/with-mp3 [mp3 "t.mp3"]
         (assoc (:id3/tag mp3) :id3.frame.name/genre ["Rock"]))))
```

I've copied the code for writing the metadata from the [official docs](https://github.com/zsau/id3) of the package.

When I try to run `-main` I get the following error:

```
(-main)
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at org.clojars.smee.binary.core/constant$fn (core.clj:278).
value 'ÿû' should have had the constant value 'ID3'
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I just use another package instead of zsau/id3?

Comment: Your dependency is super out of date. The docs mention `[zsau/id3 "1.0.0"]`, and you're using `[zsau/id3 "0.1.2"]`. I don't know why it would cause an error like this, but try updating.

Comment: When I try to use 1.0.0 I get `Error synchronising demo:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact zsau:id3:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)`. Don't know if it's relevant but I use IntelliJ Idea for my IDE and Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 11.0.1.

Comment: They seem to have forgotten to add the latest version to Clojars.

Comment: You could clone the GH repo and just run from the source code.